# node.js ERROR: connect EADDRINUSE 104.16.58.5:443

Tags: node.js

Full error:

```
    (node:8852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect EADDRINUSE 104.16.58.5:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
(node:8852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8852) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Node modules I've installed:

- Canvas@next
- Sequelize
- discord.js
- sqlite3

Other information:

- Error occurs **sometimes** when someone interacts with the app, no matter what the app does.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says EADDRINUSE - means that the port your app uses is already in use by other process (some http server using 443 as http default port)

You can change the port from 443 or you can find the process that uses this port and verify if this process is needed

For finding the process on Linux run:

```
netstat -an | grep :443
```

the second column will tell you which processId uses this port

On Windows:

```
netstat -aon | findstr 443
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I change it exactly? Because quite a lot of processes appeared (6) (I'm on windows).

Comment: can you post your Express/Hapi config that you are using?

Comment: I am not using one

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an `connect EADDRINUSE 104.16.58.5:443` error you may have no free ephemeral TCP-Port on your source computer.

There might be to many (old) TCP connections in state `TIME_WAIT`.

Please try to increase your ephemeral port range.

For reference see https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3796 and https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/434

Answer (score 0):

[Read the Oracle advise (click here)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Search.94/ATGSearchAdmin/html/s1207adjustingtcpsettingsforheavyload01.html)

> Adjusting TCP Settings for Heavy Load on Windows

The underlying Search architecture that directs searches across multiple physical partitions uses TCP/IP ports and non-blocking NIO SocketChannels to connect to the Search engines. These connections remain open in the TIME_WAIT state until the operating system times them out. Consequently, under heavy load conditions, the available ports on the machine running the Routing module can be exhausted.
On Windows platforms, the default timeout is 120 seconds, and the maximum number of ports is approximately 4,000, resulting in a maximum rate of 33 connections per second. If your index has four partitions, each search requires four ports, which provides a maximum query rate of 8.3 queries per second.
(maximum ports/timeout period)/number of partitions = maximum query rate.

If this rate is exceeded, you may see failures as the supply of TCP/IP ports is exhausted. Symptoms include drops in throughput and errors indicating failed network connections. You can diagnose this problem by observing the system while it is under load, using the netstat utility provided on most operating systems.

To avoid port exhaustion and support high connection rates, reduce the TIME_WAIT value and increase the port range.

Note: This problem does not usually appear on UNIX systems due to the higher default connection rate in those operating systems.

To set TcpTimedWaitDelay (TIME_WAIT):

Use the regedit command to access the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Services\TCPIP\Parameters registry subkey.

Create a new REG_DWORD value named TcpTimedWaitDelay.

Set the value to 60.

Stop and restart the system.

To set MaxUserPort (ephemeral port range):

Use the regedit command to access the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Services\TCPIP\Parameters registry subkey.

Create a new REG_DWORD value named MaxUserPort.

Set this value to 32768.

Stop and restart the system.